# Tumblr injecting new code into my links

Tags: javascript, html, tumblr

My Tumblr hosted website just started acting kind of strange.

a link like this `<a class="buy-button" href="https://gum.co/nyAAW">`

is turning the href into this once the page is loaded `http://t.umblr.com/redirect?z=https%3A%2F%2Fgum.co%2FnyAAW&t=ZWExNjAwMzFkM2FiMDIwMGVkZDA2NWIyOWI5ZTI0MmE1MDliNjI1OCxTSVVPN09JNA%3D%3D`

Does anybody have any idea what is happening? It seems like it's only been happening for a few days and I did not do any new updates to the site.

Comment: It seems they are farming statistics of outgoing visitor traffic.

Comment: Hmmm.. not very nice. It's breaking my code. The soundcloud api is broken now too because of the same injection.

Comment: OK, it's not all links. It is only the ones that have javascript attached to them e.g. a class that opens up a modal window, or the soundcloud player which uses a class that switches images on play/stop. You can see the website http://puremagnetik.com

Comment: @frankie. Totally OT, but that site is really lovely. Did you get the guy at geometry daily to provide the illustrations? They look amazing. And the bundles page is really nice. And the fonts! Great job.

Comment: Thanks! Yes I licensed them from Tilmann at Geometry Daily.

Comment: OK, seems like every Tumblr page has this with external links. I wonder why it's interfering with my JS though. e.g. `http://api.soundcloud.com/resolve?url=http://t.umblr.com/redirect?z=http%3A…0X72T1C3g&callback=jQuery1830808782025007531_1453842481443&_=1453842481712 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`

Comment: You might be able to add a data-link attribute for example, pass in the link as a parameter (if it is the same as a tumblr permalink curly-brackets and then write your own js to redirect the link). I can give an example. Or are these hard coded links you are writing into the post? ie not part of the template.In fact you could replace the anchor element with something else and then perhaps tumblr wont track the link behaviour.

Comment: You would need a way to target them so they must have some common attribute, class name etc for example for the javascript to work.

Comment: Each product is its own article with hard coded specifics (like the links) in it. Yes, I could target them by class name - luckily that's already in there. So you are saying to basically JS rewrite the <a> to something else so that tumblr doesn't think it's a link? Like attach a click handler or something? Perhaps I can use jquery to split the redirect url and retain only the original?

Comment: Yes, that is it more or less. Let me add an example that I made not long ago, I will try and adapt it for you.

Answer (score 4):

OK, here's how I solved it by simply parsing the code that Tumblr is injecting.

```
    function makeSingleProductCheckout(){
    $('.buy-button, .download-button').each(function() {
        $(this).attr('data-gumroad-single-product',true)
//get the original URL
       var theURL = $(this).attr('href');
//split at the equals sign
        var one = theURL.split('=');
//split again at the amperstand
        var two = one[1].split('&')
//get rif of the URL encoding
        var decodedURL = decodeURIComponent(two[0])
//put decoded URL in the href attribute
        $(this).attr('href', decodedURL)
            }
        )
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how I tried to solve something similar recently, modified for your code slightly:

```
    // create hyperlink
    var dataLinks = $('.buy-button');
    dataLinks.on('click',function(){
        var link = $(this).attr('data-href');
        $(this).attr('target','_blank');
        window.location = link; 
        return false;
    });
```

(You would need a way to add `target="_blank"` in this code, I will see if I can edit it.

So your html would need to look like this:

```
<a href="" class="buy-button" data-href="path/to/resource">Click</a>
```

Alternatively you could reaplce this with another element like so:

```
<span class="buy-button" data-href="path/to/resource">Click</span>
```

And then you could still style all `.buy-buttons` with typical href attributes

```
.buy-button {
   cursor:pointer // etc
}
```

My guess is tumblr is looking for href's that don't match the current site. But I still think you can inject your own code to alter this.  Especially if you remove the normal anchor and change the element type, untested of course!

**EDIT**

Adding `$(this).attr('target','_blank');` does work, but not sure if it is valid for a span element. I've updated the js function.

Comment: Thanks - I see what's going on here. Before I start chasing tumblr around with fixes to whatever they have changed (and will probably change again) I would like to get to the bottom of this and find out why these links are messing up my 3rd party APIs, why the soundcloud player isn't resolving or if the links are even the problem. I will try this though in the meantime. Thanks again!

Answer (score -1):

Is there a way to remove the redirect from inside the links within the post?

Edit:

I try to add script in my theme and links, but don't do nothing.
All post link shows redirect

Comment: You have to rewrite the URLs after the page loads.  `$(document).ready(function(){...`

Comment: I think I need step by step instructions :S